# Facade library/bundling pattern in CMake

Tags: cmake

We want to create and install a "facade" static library with a public self-contained/independent API on top of an existing CMake build structure using CMake. It must hide the underlying complexity of the CMake targets when installed.

We have a rather complicated hierarchy of own and 3rd-party C and C++ targets that I want to present through a pure C "facade" static library aka public API/lib to end-users; basically a set of dependent static libraries and a very small set of independent header files ONLY from the facade library; aka the public API. The facade library must hide all the underlying complexity of the targets when installed i.e. all target include directories, public headers etc. should be ignored for the facade target.

The otherwise excellent target oriented structure of CMake is working against us in this case e.g. when configuring we get errors about include directories which are prefixed in the source directories, however these include dirs are not needed when the facade target/library is used, since it by design hides all this complexity.

Is there a recommended CMake pattern for this case? We have tried capping the dependeny hierarchy by doing library bundling using a 3rd party cmake library that traversed the dependency tree and collects static library paths, thereby avoiding all the target inheritance in that way, however it has drawbacks and it tricky to maintain xplat and we would prefer a CMake idiomatic solution.

Comment: "when configuring we get errors about include directories which are prefixed in the source directories, however these include dirs are not needed ..." - This description of the problem is quite vague. Please, provide some code (ideally, in the form of [mcve]) and the error message it causes.

Comment: The errors are not really the point here, when in our own targets can be avoided by prefixing all include directories with $<BUILD_INTERFACE:...> but this is not feasible or practical with 3rd party libraries. I can provide an example, but the issue is really that we cannot make these changes everywhere and not to 3rd party libraries/targets.

Comment: As I said, the code could help to **understand** your problem, which otherwise is described in words, which could mean... almost anything. E,g, in your comment you write "when in our own targets can be avoided by prefixing all include directories with $<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>", which (from my understanding) means, that your problem is about **installed** libraries, but no word in your question post reminds about installation. Just show your code and the error message. Also describe why "direct" fixing the error is not feasible in your case.

Comment: Distribute all 3rd parties in docker.

Comment: @KamilCuk distributing the 3rd party libraries pre-built and importing separately is definitely a possible solution.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I mentioned install in the first sentence of the question, however I'm sorry if you misunderstood. I've received your critique of my question clearly.

I have at least three different approaches for a solution now;
- Use superbuild pattern instead of install
- Prebuild 3rd party libraries as suggested above
- Forcing the 3rd party libraries out of the dependency graph and force the consumers to add the dependencies manually

Comment: Let me guess about your problem. 1. You include a 3-d party project with `add_subdirectory(lib1)`. 2. That project creates a library and attaches include directories to it via `target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC ...)`. 3. That included project doesn't install the library, so it doesn't bother with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>`. 4. In your main project your create the static library `facade` and link it with 3-d party library. 5. Then you install your library and export it. 6. Because facade is STATIC, CMake requires to install `lib1` too. Because of (3) this gives the error.

Comment: Does my above understanding correct? (For being clearer, it should contain much more code, but a *comment* has a **limited length**. Unlike to the *question post*.)